# How to monitor virtual memory in windows 11?

Tags: virtual-memory, windows-11

I want to see how much virtual memory I am using, and have watched multiple tutorials, but can't seem to find any on windows 11. I have tried using performance-monitor, but I am unable to find virtual memory. In the tuturials I have watched it is under 'Paging File' pane, but I think it is moved or in another pane in windows 11?

I am not trying to allocate space for virtualy memory or see how much is allocated. I want to monitor how much of it is actually used realtime.

Comment: Task Manager indicates how large your page file is.

Comment: @Ramhound, where?

Comment: The same location that it’s been displayed for the last 5 years within Windows 10 (Windows 11 at its core is Windows 10 and Task Manager hasn’t changed)

Comment: @Ramhound, well I don't know where it has been displayed for 5 years...

Answer (score 1):

You can use either Process Hacker or Process Explorer in Windows 11.

I have tested both and Process Hacker seems to have better information about pagefile.

Comment: Thank you, I found a way, but will have a look at this aswell.